# CD RIP SLOW on Ubuntu 12.04. How can I increase ripping speed?

Tags: 12.04, cd

I'm trying to rip an audio cd from my old library but when I try (with every app) to do that, the process is too slow. For 2 tracks it need more than 2 hour and then it crash!

I tried to make:

```
$ sudo hdparm -d1 /dev/sr0
```

but the response is

```
$ /dev/s$ /dev/sr0:
```

setting using_dma to 1 (on)

HDIO_SET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

HDIO_GET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
r0:

```
setting using_dma to 1 (on)

HDIO_SET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

HDIO_GET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Comment: I am having a similar issue.  Ripping a CD takes 10 minutes per track even though my laptop has mad specs.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Upgraded my Ubuntu, then run perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using /dev/sr0, use the correct entry from /dev/disk/by-id

For example, I run abcde with the option `CDROM=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-PIONEER_DVD-RW_DVR-106D_CJDC269789WL` and it now rips at full speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to do it is

```
setcd -x <speed> <device>
```

See the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/setcd.1.html) for details on how speed is expressed. Or rip using this little script,

[nenRip](https://github.com/OlaAronsson/nenRip) I made and configure CDROM_SPEED in there.